# ¿Cómo validar formulario, con dos campos en base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

Estoy trabajando con un pequeño formulario de solo un campo a validar, dicho campo valida un PIN introducido:

```
<form action="validar.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>PIN<span class='required'>*</span></label>
       <input type='text' form-control name='pinWrite' id='pinWrite' required="">
   </div>
 </div>
<form>
```

Esta validación lo hace sólo si existe en la tabla registros, pero quiero que valide otro llamado "rango", de la siguiente tabla:

```
 id_registro |  pin  |   rango   | 
    1          xxxx    más de 50
    2          zzzz    menos de 50
```

Si el pin se encuentra en un rango "más de 50" que no pueda acceder al de "menos de 50" y viceversa.

Mi consulta de validación es la siguiente:

```
  $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "norma035");
  $consulta = "SELECT * FROM empresasregistradas WHERE pin = 
  '$pin_obtenido'";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
```

PD: Los registros se ingresan en otro formulario, esta validación es como un login independiente.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías agregar una variable de control con la cual acceda a dichas ventanas  por ejemplo:

```
if(($resultado->num_rows)>0){ //Para comprobar si hay algún resultado
  $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado); //Para guardarlo como arreglo
  if($rows['rango'] == "menos de 50"){ //Con esta condición comparamos si el rango usuario que encontró es igual a "menos de 50"
    $variableControl = true;
  }
}
```

Y en el panel donde accedes usas esta variable para saber si true = es menos de 50 o false = más de 50.

> PD: Si te marca un error en num_rows es porque la consulta devuelve un error.

Comment: Así es amigo @Luis son ventanas diferentes. + de 50 y -50

Comment: La consulta al valida el pin quedaría exactamente igual?

Answer (score 0):

me ha funcionado unicamente modificar la consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM empresasregistradas WHERE pin = '$pin_obtenido' AND rango ='Mas de 50'";
```